# SSE rounding precision

Tags: c++, optimization, rounding, sse

I have a small problem with SSE rounding. The code is self explanatory, I am trying to get the count of 0.0001s in 293.05694580 including some rounding (e.g. there are 52 0.1s in 5.21)...

```
#include <xmmintrin.h> 
#include <emmintrin.h> 

int main(void)
{
    float val       = (float) 293.05694580;
    float tickSize  = (float)   0.0001;

    __m128 _val     = _mm_set_ps1( val );
    __m128 _shift   = _mm_set_ps1( 1 / tickSize );

    /* 293.0569480 * 10000 should be 2930569.480 */
    __m128 _mul     = _mm_mul_ps(_val, _shift);

    /* Rounding 2930569.480 should get 2930569, but returns 2930570 instead. Why? */
    __m128i _ticks  = _mm_cvtps_epi32( _mul );
}
```

Lastly, how can I revert the ordering of results in _ticks? 
Many thanks, 
Daniel

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with SSE. It's just the usual floating-point gotchas.

Comment: @CAFxY: Can you elaborate on maintainable and working code? Im eager to learn, but as I wrote below, I usually perform this a trillion times or more so I need it to be fast, hence SSE.

Comment: @Mystical: So there should be a simple workaround, right?

Comment: @DanBencik: not really. The workaround is to understand your code, and that's not really simple. Not all values can be accurately represented in binary (or, for that matter, in decimal) notation. So you need to write your code in a way that either avoids such representations, or which is able to cope with the loss of precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the intermediate result, don't assume it

check/set sse rounding mode

for counting something use integers

Comment: hey bla, "for counting use integers" - do you mean incrementing some temp value from zero until I reach val and noting the number of increments? This operation Im trying to do will typically be done a trillion times and takes up 25 percent of the total runtime so I need it to be fast. if you had some other method in mind, I will be glad to learn something new. As for sse rounding mode, it should normally be set to "round to nearest" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxty7t75(v=vs.80).aspx) which is the right one.

Comment: sorry, that was not what i meant by counting. first of all u have a typo there 4580 instead of 480. and you should probably use ss (single scalar) and not ps functions or no sse at all, it's not always faster. and you should start your debugger (visual c++?) and step through it, watch rounding control bit in and be sure it's set to what you like (the fpu has it's defaults but e.g. in plugin development you have to check/set it). and your example gives an inexact result which is normal (precision flag indicates this btw), 2930569.5 is inexact but expected, rounds to nearest 2930570.

Comment: for mxcsr see http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/sse.php, mxcsr can be watched in the visual c++ debugger.

Comment: and for preciser (intermediate) results use double precision, that is "double" in c or sd/pd instead of ss/ps instructions for sse. in your example with double precision the end result would probably be correct.

Comment: bla, thank you for recommendations. The example is done just with one number, however in real life, I will be calculating these values on large arrays. Hence, I need to use SSE. As for double/float, for obvious reasons floats give roughly double performance.

Comment: bla, I made a double version (had to figure out about shuffling and packing first) and it works nicely. It is about 2x slower than the float version, however it's reliable and still makes my code 10x faster (in general, combining calculation of inputs + their tranformation into tick counts). Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The final code, if somebody cares, is

```
inline void QTickCalcer::tickCountsFromDoubleArray(
        const double * src, int * dest, const unsigned int elemCount) const 
{
/*  src and dest need to be align_malloced              */
__m128i * r  = (__m128i*)dest;

__m128i r1;
__m128i r2;
__m128i rTot;

__m128d * d1 = (__m128d*) & src[0];
__m128d * d2 = (__m128d*) & src[2];

__m128d tmp1;
__m128d tmp2;

for ( register unsigned int i = 0; i < elemCount/4; i++ )
{
    tmp1    = _mm_mul_pd( *d1,  this->_dshiftor);           
    tmp2    = _mm_mul_pd( *d2,  this->_dshiftor);           

    /*  Interleave - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8c5hx3b(v=vs.71).aspx                 */      
    r1  = _mm_cvtpd_epi32 ( tmp1 );
    r2  = _mm_cvtpd_epi32 ( tmp2 );
    rTot = _mm_unpacklo_epi32 ( r1, r2 );

    /*  Shuffle to match the ordering in src - http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/309988  */
    *r = _mm_shuffle_epi32( rTot, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,1,2,0));

    d1 += 2;
    d2 += 2;
    r++;
}
};
```

Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: *r = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(_mm_cvtpd_epi32(tmp1), _mm_cvtpd_epi32(tmp2));

Answer (score 0):

For performance and precision, maybe you could:

- use double precision only in an precision exception handler (unmask precision exceptions)
- if the requirement is "needs X digits for dollar cents" you could put big money into double arrays and small money into float arrays. before that calculate from X at what number you split it

Comment: Oops, I noticed your post only now. I have already made it in doubles and the speedup of SSE over regular code is 10x, so Im happy with that. But many thanks to you too!